# how to check if a url has a substring

Tags: c#, winforms, url, browser

I am trying to make something that will enable all controls if a SubString in a WebBrowser matches a
SubString in a TextBox and if it does it will enable all controls, but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is my current code:

```
string str = "www.google.com";

int pos = str.IndexOf(".") + 1;
int pos2 = str.LastIndexOf(".") - 4;
string str2 = str.Substring(pos, pos2);

if (webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(pos, pos2) == textBox1.Text.Substring(pos, pos2))
{
    foreach (Control c in Controls)
    {
        c.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: firstly I don't think you mean to have `-4` when setting `pos2`. Secondly, you seem to be comparing the same substring operations? Can you provide example of TextBox values that you would use, and specifcally what parts you want to match (in text value)

Comment: Make sure you consider the case of the text as well.

Comment: -4 is right (for the example given). OP wants to get google.com when extracting the substring. However the name is confusing. That's len of the substring to be retrieved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class is a wonderful thing.

```
Uri google = new Uri("http://www.google.com/");
if (webBrowser.Url.Host == google.Host){
}
```

Or even simply:

```
if (webBrower.Url.Host.ToLower().Contains("google")) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use [string.contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx)

```
if(textBox1.Text.ToLower().Contains(str.ToLower()))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ONLY need to know that the substring exists within the string, use `String.Contains` as Justin Pihony suggested.

If you need to know **where** in the string it exists, use [`String.IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx).  If the string doesn't exist at all, this method will return -1.